# No idea why my livewire function is not working, just goes to a blank page after clicking function?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a livewire function that is not firing for some reason and I have no idea why?

This is what the blade view looks like:

all_users.blade.php:

```
<div>
            @livewire('add-friend')
    </div>
```

add-friend.blade.php:
When I click the addToFriend function it goes to a blank page, I have no idea why it isn't working

```
 <div>
        @foreach ($users as $user)

            <div class="container2">



                @if($user->attributes==null)
                    <img class="profImg" src="{{ url('storage/images/default-image-620x600.jpeg') }}"/>

                    <p> {{$user->name}}</p>

                    <p >Grade is: ?</p>

                    <p >Age is: ?</p>

                    <p >Country is: ?</p>


                @endif

                @if($user->attributes!=null)

                    @if($user->attributes->ProfileImage!=null)
                        <img class="profImg" src="{{ url('storage/images/'.$user->attributes->ProfileImage) }}"/>
                    @else
                        <img class="profImg" src="{{ url('storage/images/default-image-620x600.jpeg') }}"/>

                    @endif
                        <p> {{$user->name}}</p>
                            <p>Gender {{$user->attributes->Gender}}</p>
                    @if($user->attributes->GradeLevel!=null)
                        <p >Grade is: {{$user->attributes->GradeLevel}}</p>
                    @else
                        <p >Grade is: ?</p>
                    @endif
                    @if($user->attributes->Age!=null)
                        <p class="ex1">Age is {{$user->attributes->Age}}</p>
                    @else
                        <p >Age is: ?</p>
                    @endif
                    @if($user->attributes->Country!=null)
                        <p>Country is {{$user->attributes->Country}}</p>
                    @else
                        <p>Country is: ?</p>
                    @endif
                @endif


@if(Auth::user()->hasSentFriendRequestTo($user))
                    <x-button  type="submit" class="btn btn-red">Requested</x-button>
                @elseif(Auth::user()->isFriendWith($user))
                    <x-button class="btn btn-green"  type="submit" >Friends</x-button>
                @else
                    <form wire:submit.prevent="addToFriend" method="POST">
                        <input type="number" wire:model="user" value="{{$user->id}}" >
                        @csrf
                        <x-button  type="submit"  class="btn btn-warning"> Add Friend</x-button>
                    </form>

               
           

            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
```

This is what the AddFriend component looks like as well:

```
class AddFriend extends Component
{
    public $user;

    public function render()
    {
        $users = User::where('id', '!=', Auth::user()->id)->limit(14)->latest()->get();

        $usersid=User::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->pluck('id');

        return view('livewire.add-friend',
        ['users'=>$users]);
    }

    public function addToFriend(User $user)
    {
        $username = Auth::user();
        $recipient = User::find($user->id);

            if ($username->befriend($recipient)) {
                $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('alert', ['type' => 'success', 'message' => 'Request has been sent!']);

            } else {
                $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('alert', ['type' => 'error', 'message' => 'Request has been failed!']);
            }

        }

    }
```

App.blade.php:

This is what the app.blade.php looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

        <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Social climbers') }}</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&display=swap">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/1.9.6/tailwind.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@tailwindcss/typography@0.2.x/dist/typography.min.css" />

        <!-- Styles -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
        <link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
            <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
        <script src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
        
@livewireStyles

            <!-- Scripts -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

    </head>
    <body class="font-sans antialiased">
    @livewireScripts

    <div class="min-h-screen bg-gray-100">
            @include('layouts.navigation')

            <!-- Page Heading -->
            <header class="bg-white shadow">
                <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto py-6 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                </div>
            </header>

            <!-- Page Content -->
            <main>
                @yield('content')


            </main>
        </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('js/bootstrap.js')}}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you sure livewirescripts is loaded in the view?

Comment: I've the app.blade.php now. I'm sure the scripts are being loaded

Comment: maybe your livewire script tag should be under the main div in app.blade.php

Comment: You are going to need to look in the developer tools, network tab and see what happens when you click the button

Comment: Try removing the `<form>` and adding your `addToFriend` function to the submit button. 

If you keep the form you can also use `<form wire:submit.prevent="submit">` and allow Livewire to handle the submission.

Livewire doesn't need a form tag to work, but if you intend to post to a standard controller then keep it, and remove anything livewire related.